# How to combine training and testing dataset in same format

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I am practicing with this dataset: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Census+Income

I loaded training & testing data.

```
# Downloading train and test data
trainFile = "adult.data"; testFile = "adult.test"

if (!file.exists (trainFile))
download.file (url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data",
destfile = trainFile)

if (!file.exists (testFile))
download.file (url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test",
destfile = testFile)

# Assigning column names
colNames = c ("age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education",
"educationnum", "maritalstatus", "occupation",
"relationship", "race", "sex", "capitalgain",
"capitalloss", "hoursperweek", "nativecountry",
"incomelevel")

# Reading training data
training = read.table (trainFile, header = FALSE, sep = ",",
strip.white = TRUE, col.names = colNames,
na.strings = "?", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# Load the testing data set
testing = read.table (testFile, header = FALSE, sep = ",",
strip.white = TRUE, col.names = colNames,
na.strings = "?", fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

I needed to combined two into one. But, there is a problem. I am seeing structure of the two data is not same.

Display structure of the training data

```
> str (training)
'data.frame': 32561 obs. of 15 variables:
$ age : int 39 50 38 53 28 37 49 52 31 42 ...
$ workclass : Factor w/ 8 levels "Federal-gov",..: 7 6 4 4 4 4 4 6 4 4 ...
$ fnlwgt : int 77516 83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187 209642 45781 159449 ...
$ education : Factor w/ 16 levels "10th","11th",..: 10 10 12 2 10 13 7 12 13 10 ...
$ educationnum : int 13 13 9 7 13 14 5 9 14 13 ...
$ maritalstatus: Factor w/ 7 levels "Divorced","Married-AF-spouse",..: 5 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 5 3 ...
$ occupation : Factor w/ 14 levels "Adm-clerical",..: 1 4 6 6 10 4 8 4 10 4 ...
$ relationship : Factor w/ 6 levels "Husband","Not-in-family",..: 2 1 2 1 6 6 2 1 2 1 ...
$ race : Factor w/ 5 levels "Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 5 5 5 3 3 5 3 5 5 5 ...
$ sex : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
$ capitalgain : int 2174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 ...
$ capitalloss : int 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ hoursperweek : int 40 13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 ...
$ nativecountry: Factor w/ 41 levels "Cambodia","Canada",..: 39 39 39 39 5 39 23 39 39 39 ...
$ incomelevel : Factor w/ 2 levels "<=50K",">50K": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
```

Display structure of the testing data

```
> str (testing)
'data.frame': 16282 obs. of 15 variables:
$ age : Factor w/ 74 levels "|1x3 Cross validator",..: 1 10 23 13 29 3 19 14 48 9 ...
$ workclass : Factor w/ 9 levels "","Federal-gov",..: 1 5 5 3 5 NA 5 NA 7 5 ...
$ fnlwgt : int NA 226802 89814 336951 160323 103497 198693 227026 104626 369667 ...
$ education : Factor w/ 17 levels "","10th","11th",..: 1 3 13 9 17 17 2 13 16 17 ...
$ educationnum : int NA 7 9 12 10 10 6 9 15 10 ...
$ maritalstatus: Factor w/ 8 levels "","Divorced",..: 1 6 4 4 4 6 6 6 4 6 ...
$ occupation : Factor w/ 15 levels "","Adm-clerical",..: 1 8 6 12 8 NA 9 NA 11 9 ...
$ relationship : Factor w/ 7 levels "","Husband","Not-in-family",..: 1 5 2 2 2 5 3 6 2 6 ...
$ race : Factor w/ 6 levels "","Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 1 4 6 6 4 6 6 4 6 6 ...
$ sex : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Female","Male": 1 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 ...
$ capitalgain : int NA 0 0 0 7688 0 0 0 3103 0 ...
$ capitalloss : int NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ hoursperweek : int NA 40 50 40 40 30 30 40 32 40 ...
$ nativecountry: Factor w/ 41 levels "","Cambodia",..: 1 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 ...
$ incomelevel : Factor w/ 3 levels "","<=50K.",">50K.": 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 ...
```

#### Problem 1:

`age` has become `factor` at testing. and all other **levels of factor** in `testing` is being **increased by 1** than **levels of factor** in `training`. This is because first row is an unnecessary row in testing.

```
|1x3 Cross validator
```

I tried to get rid of this by re-assigning testing:

```
testing = testing[-1,]
```

but, after running `str()` command again, I don't see any change.

#### Problem 2:

Like I said at previous, I needed to combine those two data-frame into one data-frame. So, I run this:

```
combined <- rbind(training , testing)
```

Besides the problem-1, I can see new a problem after running `str()`

```
> str(combined)
'data.frame':   48842 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ age          : chr  "39" "50" "38" "53" ...
 $ workclass : Factor w/ 9 levels "Federal-gov",..: 7 6 4 4 4 4 4 6 4 4 ...
 $ fnlwgt       : int  77516 83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187 209642 45781 159449 ...
 $ education    : Factor w/ 17 levels "10th","11th",..: 10 10 12 2 10 13 7 12 13 10 ...
 $ educationnum : int  13 13 9 7 13 14 5 9 14 13 ...
 $ maritalstatus: Factor w/ 8 levels "Divorced","Married-AF-spouse",..: 5 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 5 3 ...
 $ occupation   : Factor w/ 15 levels "Adm-clerical",..: 1 4 6 6 10 4 8 4 10 4 ...
 $ relationship : Factor w/ 7 levels "Husband","Not-in-family",..: 2 1 2 1 6 6 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ race         : Factor w/ 6 levels "Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 5 5 5 3 3 5 3 5 5 5 ...
 $ sex          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Female","Male",..: 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ capitalgain  : int  2174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 ...
 $ capitalloss  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hoursperweek : int  40 13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 ...
 $ nativecountry: Factor w/ 42 levels "Cambodia","Canada",..: 39 39 39 39 5 39 23 39 39 39 ...
 $ incomelevel  : Factor w/ 5 levels "<=50K",">50K",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
```

factor levels at target variable (`incomelevel`) in `combined` data-frame is **5** where it's **2** (which is correct) in the `training` data-frame and **3** (increased by 1 for problem-1) in `testing` data-frame. This is because there is a `. (dot)` after each value at `incomelevel` in `testing` data-frame `(<=50K., <=50K., >50K.,......)`. So, I need to remove that `.(dot)` But, I am not getting idea how to remove it. Is there any function?

I am very in data and r. That's why, facing this type of basic issues. Can you please help me to solve the issue I am facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can ignore the first line of test, this will solve the issue of age being a factor, because it seems like a header:

```
head(readLines(testFile))
[1] "|1x3 Cross validator"                                                                                                                 
[2] "25, Private, 226802, 11th, 7, Never-married, Machine-op-inspct, Own-child, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K."              
[3] "38, Private, 89814, HS-grad, 9, Married-civ-spouse, Farming-fishing, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 50, United-States, <=50K."
```

We run your code, we can use read.csv, with skip=1 for test:

```
colNames = c ("age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education",
"educationnum", "maritalstatus", "occupation",
"relationship", "race", "sex", "capitalgain",
"capitalloss", "hoursperweek", "nativecountry",
"incomelevel")

# Reading training data
training = read.csv (trainFile, header = FALSE, col.names = colNames,stringsAsFactors = TRUE,na.strings = "?",strip.white = TRUE)

testing = read.csv (testFile, header = FALSE, col.names = colNames,na.strings = "?",stringsAsFactors = TRUE,skip=1,strip.white = TRUE)
```

Now, the income level, unfortunately we have to correct it manually, it's a good thing you check:

```
testing$incomelevel = factor(gsub("\\.","",as.character(testing$incomelevel)))
```

We check levels, only difference is native country:

```
all.equal(sapply(testing,levels) ,sapply(training,levels))
[1] "Component “nativecountry”: Lengths (40, 41) differ (string compare on first 40)"
[2] "Component “nativecountry”: 26 string mismatches"
```

And I don't think there's much you can do, maybe you have to remove it before / after joining:

```
setdiff(levels(training$nativecountry),levels(testing$nativecountry))
[1] "Holand-Netherlands"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!